# How to suppress shortcode given a particular string in url in php

Tags: php, url, shortcode

I am trying to suppress a particular shortcode like [some-button] whenever the string "/?s=" shows up in the URL because search results pages don't need it but that shortcode is used in lots of other places throughout the website.

Example:
https://s1.temporary-access.com/~allacros/devel/ablah
should still have all shortcodes working.

However:
https://s1.temporary-access.com/~allacros/devel/?s=tahiti
should have the [some-button] shortcode suppressed.  (Note: you can see the bug I'm trying to get rid of if you follow this link)

What is the best way to do this in PHP (for a Wordpress site)?

I imagine that whatever function that does this has to be in functions.php in my theme?

Comment: you'll have to filter the post before `do_shortcode` is called and remove them, unless you have control over the shortcode code.  Then you could just return '' from the shortcode in that case.  You could/maybe able do this filtering within another shortcode that wraps the shortcodes you want to remove.  `[shortcodeFilter] Some content [shortcode_to_supress] [/shortcodeFilter]`

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I think you have to call `do_shortcode` on the contents of a shortcode that contains other shortcodes.  But it's been a while sense I did that so I could be wrong.  If that is the case you can simply remove all shortcodes `preg_replace('/\[[^]]+\]/', '', $content)` after checking the url, instead of calling `do_shortcode`

Comment: I managed to get it working if I put spaghetti code in my functions.php file.  I did the following:  if ( !(empty( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/?s=") ) ) )   remove_shortcode('some-button');     However, if I put it inside a function like function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query(), it seems like it's not working because it's not responding to add_action('wp','remove_shortcode_exec_on_query');  Is there a proper way to hook into wordpress to execute this function instead of ignoring it?